# How to import node-js dependency in webpack project if package already includes types definitions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

[chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) library already includes types definitions, and there is no need to use deprecated [@types/chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chalk) package. However, I got error `TS2307: Cannot find module 'chalk'`.

[image]

The `chalk` library project structure is:

[image]

What I did wrong? I tried [colors.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) library instead - same error.

Node: my project is build by Webpack for `Node.js`. Off course, webpack has been configured for node (includes `target: 'node'` option and `nodeExternals` plugin usage).

---

Link to project with problem reproduction:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aro46dXM9rTw6IsaTv5TEzzXEp_sCJTQ/view?usp=sharing

Node.js installation required, and as always, `npm i` command before run project building.

Comment: Do you still have the same error after `npm install chalk` ?

Comment: @Seblor I install with `npm install chalk -d  -E`. If there is no difference between it and plain `npm install chalk` in this case, my answer is "Yes".

Comment: If `chalk` is used in your final build, you might want to install it with the `-S` flag instead of `-D`. Depending if your IDE uses the dependencies or devDependencies to resolve / check modules, it might change something. Have you tried an other IDE to see if the same error pops up ?

Comment: @Seblor, are you sure about `-S`? I has not been see this flag in [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) ...

Comment: -S is the same as --save. It puts the installed module as a dependency instead of a dev dependency. Dev dependencies should only be modules used for dev purposes like webpack, babel, eslint, etc...

Comment: @Seblor I did what you said. Unfortunately, zero effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, `"moduleResolution": "node"` was missed in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix it manual by following command:

```
npm install chalk
npm install each-async
npm install indent-string
```

in case it doesn't work you need to clear cash and check the config in webpack.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please enplane, what kind of relationship `each-async` and  `indent-string` has to resolving of TypeScript types. Why TypeScript cannot resolve it's types without `each-async` and  `indent-string`?